# Why "error Image is not defined" in svelte local, but working in REPL?

Tags: image, svelte, sveltekit

I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: Image is not defined
```

The code is in a component and looks like this:

```
    // Preload images
    for (const name in images) {
      (new Image()).src = images[name]
    }
```

The only thing I did is a exact copy of this working [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/9876cca0f1c2410b8920fec3fbc81375?version=3.44.2) in local, there it works but in local it doesn't. These lines are under the piece.svelte component.

I'm very new at js, I imagine I'm missing some basics. Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Image` is part of the browser API, it creates an `<img>` element and cannot be used at the top level when using SvelteKit: During server-side rendering it will not be available.

You can access the DOM in [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount).

Comment: Not 100% how would this solve the problem, but thanks for the aclaration, still don't know why the REPL example works and mine doesn't, it shouldn't be available for the example either right?

Comment: The REPL is fully running in the browser, it does not do server-side rendering and thus always has access to the browser APIs.